# Recipe not being executed in Chef

Tags: chef-infra, apt, recipe, cookbook

I'm making a simple recipe that apt-get upgrades the whole system.

```
include_recipe "apt"

execute "apt-get upgrade -y" do
        command "apt-get upgrade -y"
        action :nothing
end
```

but it never gets run:

```
chef-solo -j node.json -W

Recipe: up2date::default
  * execute[apt-get upgrade -y] action nothing[2012-11-12T13:05:04+01:00] 
    INFO: Processing execute[apt-get upgrade -y] 
    action nothing (up2date::default line 12)  (up to date)
```

Can't understand why ?

Is there a better/cleaner way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are including "apt" recipe you don't have to create *execute[apt-get upgrade -y]* resource. Or if you don't want to include "apt" recipe, then use

```
execute "apt-get upgrade -y" do
    command "apt-get upgrade -y"
    action :run
end
```

But as run is default action, and name is default command, that can be shortened to

```
execute "apt-get upgrade -y"
```

Comment: thanks; just execute "apt-get upgrade -y" without a 'do' block ?

Comment: Are you saying that the "apt" recipe will automatically run apt-get upgrade? Because it doesn't seem to for me.

Comment: Yes, it will. In your case may be something from your cookbook overwrites the resource. I don't know.